# how to upload file by robot framework without input type=file

Tags: robotframework, selenium2library

Is It Possible for Selenium2Library? about upload file in some kind of website using upload like this http://www.dropzonejs.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium requires you to give it a input type with the keyword "Choose File" and then where the file lives. - [Selenium2Library](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Choose%20File)

You can use [Autoit](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/), which allows you to interact with the file browser which will pop up once you tell Selenium to click on the form. Its not perfect but its something.